# Using a formula for Excel Cell Reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have excel data points that are variable distances below each other such as
A1
A3
A6
A10
A15

I want to write a formula that can be dragged down to reference all the data in a sequential form so that B1 references A1, B2 references A3, B3 references A6 and so on. Is this possible in excel?

I have tried to write a reference in the form of "=A(5*C1)" but excel just throws a reference error. If this is possible any help would be great.

Comment: Try using [`INDIRECT`](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/indirect.html)

Comment: In `B1` try: `=INDEX(A:A,ROW()*(ROW()+1)/2)` if you're trying to utilize the triangular number sequence. Otherwise, return the sequence in an array: `=INDEX(A:A,INDEX({1;3;6;10;15},ROW()))`.

Comment: `INDIRECT()` function should be avoided in all means, however if there is no option then you may need to use, perhaps this is good read **[INDIRECT – Excel’s Most Evil Function](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2016/04/25/indirect-excels-most-evil-function/#:~:text=So%20what%20makes%20INDIRECT%20so%20evil%3F%201%20Its,External%20workbooks%20...%205%20Difficult%20to%20debug%20)**

Comment: @VBasic2008 nice one on `ROW(A1)*(ROW(A1)+1)/2`

Answer (score 1):

You can use INDEX combined with SCAN:

```
=INDEX(A:A,SCAN(,SEQUENCE(5),LAMBDA(a,b,SUM(a)+b)))
```

Or you can hardcore it:
`=INDEX(A:A,{1,3,6,10,15})`

Comment: This would be dynamic I assume: `=INDEX(A:A,SCAN(,SEQUENCE(ROWS(TOCOL(A:A,1))),LAMBDA(a,b,SUM(a)+b)))`

Comment: @Mayukh likely, but without data or samples we don't know.